How to connect RPi 3A+ to WiFi without having WiFI connection in the first instance?
I thought I was able to achieve this previously by adding the file wpa_supplicant.conf to the directory /rootfs/etc/wpa_supplicant. The file is of the form:
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="WiFiName1"
    psk="WiFiPassword1"
}

network={
    ssid="WiFiName2"
    psk="WiFiPassword2"
}

However, this no longer seems to be working. I edit the microSD file via my laptop, altering the wpa_supplicant.conf file to be as above. I then insert the card to my RPi and connect a power supply. The RPi appears to boot, as the on board LEDs show, but I am unable to ssh or ping via either of the above two networks.
Alternatively, I tried adding the wpa_supplicant.conf file to the '/bootfs/' directory.
No luck through this approach either.
I believe the above steps worked for me previously, but I must be mis-recalling something. Can someone please point out my mistake ?

What OS is installed (detail including version)? You have provided no details of WHAT YOU HAVE DONE.
