SSH unexpectedly won't connect
The problem
When first booting my Raspberry Pi 3A+, I had trouble connecting over SSH.
Either:

I would enter my SSH password, then the session would freeze
After entering my SSH password, the session would show the RPi command line. However, I could not type any input. The session was frozen.
After accessing the RPi command line, I could enter several commands before, ultimately, the session would freeze.

After a while of tinkering, I solved the problem. I believe the solution I used was to increase the size of my RPi SWAP, in the /etc/dphys-swapfile, to 2048:
CONF_SWAPSIZE=2048

No problems for half a year. Recently, I have been running some custom scripts, and all of a sudden the problem has returned.
Solution attempts
First, I considered I may be out of memory on my microSD. I checked the free space on my microSD and this is not a problem.
I checked the 'dphys-swapfile' and the same limit, as mentioned above, exists for the SWAP.
I rebooted my Pi. The problem remains.
I attempted logging into my pi with the command:
ssh -o IPQoS=none user@raspberry.local

The problem remains.
System Info
I am using a Raspberry Pi 3A+, with the Raspberry Pi Operating System, formerly known as Raspbian. This Operating System is a fork of Debian. Specifically:
Debian version: 12 (bookworm)

Can anyone suggest a solution, given that, without being able to ssh into my Pi, I can only monitor the system by removing my microSD, and reading it on my laptop ?
Update
The following day, I have rebooted my RaspberryPi, attempted to log in via SSH and... success.
After the many attempts yesterday, I have changed nothing on my Pi other than waiting approximately 12 hours.
Such unpredictable behaviour is undesirable. Can anyone suggest means to diagnose the issue after the fact ? Does there exist a log of attempted connections on the RPiOS, with reasons for their failure ? Perhaps the issue is somehow due to the external modem connection - if so, how would I attempt to diagnose this ?

You have failed to respond to questions in your previous post; provided no details. Is your network still broken? Which networking system? Without these it is impossible to answer.

Hi Milliways, no, my network is not broken, in so far as I am able to use it as normal from all other devices. I am connecting to my home WiFi network via a wireless connection. Other than that, I am not sure what you mean by 'which networking system'.

You said so in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/150057/8697 What you posted there is wrong for dhcpcd meaningless for networkmanager.
